# Insert query is not working "Query was empty" I need to insert the data that is displayed on the table

Tags: php, insert

```
    if(isset($_POST['insert']))
              {
              $index=1;
              while($index <= $count) ##inserting the values in db
              {
                $loan = $_POST["loan_amount$index"];
                $interest1 = $_POST["int1$index"];
                $interest2 = $_POST["int2$index"];
                $interest3 = $_POST["int3$index"];
                $interest4 = $_POST["int4$index"];
                $interest5 = $_POST["int5$index"];
                $interest6 = $_POST["int6$index"];
                $interest7 = $_POST["int7$index"];
                $interest8 = $_POST["int8$index"];
                $interest9 = $_POST["int9$index"];
                $interest10 = $_POST["int10$index"];
                $forOdNextMonth = $_POST["due1$index"];
                $forOdNextMonth1 = $_POST["due2$index"];
                $forOdNextMonth2 = $_POST["due3$index"];
                $forOdNextMonth3 = $_POST["due4$index"];
                $forOdNextMonth4 = $_POST["due5$index"];
                $forOdNextMonth5 = $_POST["due6$index"];
                $forOdNextMonth6 = $_POST["due7$index"];
                $forOdNextMonth7 = $_POST["due8$index"];
                $forOdNextMonth8 = $_POST["due9$index"];
                $forOdNextMonth9 = $_POST["due10$index"];
                $total= $_POST["total$index"];
```

insert query:

```
     $insertsql = "INSERT INTO `members_details` 
(loan_amount,int1,int2,int3,int4,int5,int6,int7,int8,int9,int10,due1,due2,due3, due4, due5,due6,due7,due8,due9,due10,total) 
VALUES(
    '".$loan."',
    '".$interest1."',
    '".$interest2."',
    '".$interest3."',
    '".$interest4."',
    '".$interest5."',
    '".$interest6."',           
    '".$interest7."',
    '".$interest8."',
    '".$interest9."',
    '".$interest10."',
    '".$forOdNextMonth."',
    '".$forOdNextMonth1."',
    '".$forOdNextMonth2."',
    '".$forOdNextMonth3."',           
    '".$forOdNextMonth4."',
    '".$forOdNextMonth5."',
    '".$forOdNextMonth6."',
    '".$forOdNextMonth7."',
    '".$forOdNextMonth8."',
    '".$forOdNextMonth9."',
    '".$total."')";
    mysql_query($insertsql) or die(mysql_error());
    $index++;  //incrementing index
    }
      }
```

This is the code that shows the error.

Comment: Can you reduce the code in the question to just the relevant parts, at the moment there is a lot of code and no real indication of what the problem is and what specific piece of code is causing the problem.

Comment: That's a bunch of code. I wonder if anyone will read it. Can't you just post **relevants** parts?

Comment: is it okay now???  should i make any change?

Comment: @Cid pls can u do it ??

Comment: Result of `var_dump($insertsql);` please.

Comment: Note that your query is vulnerable to [SQL Injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) consider using prepared statements with [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). Note that [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) is deprecated since PHP 5.5.0 and was removed in php 7.x

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query is deprecated from PHP 5.5 onwards - http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php.

Please use mysqli.

To connect to db using mysqli and php:

```
<?php 
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');
```

To run queries:

```
   $sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
           VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

   if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
   } else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
   }
```

Regarding your error, try running the queries using mysqli.